# Error: The value of attribute "xmlns:tools" associated with an element type "FrameLayout" must not contain the '<' character

Tags: java, android

I have an error D:\Project Android\My Mall\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:3:6: Error: The value of attribute "xmlns:tools" associated with an element type "FrameLayout" must not contain the '<' character.

the code in string.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.and>
    <string name=" title_activity_main>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="nav_header_title">Android Studio</string>
    <string name="nav_header_subtitle">android.studio@android.com</string>
    <string name="nav_header_desc">Navigation header</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>

</FrameLayout>
    ">MainActivity</string></FrameLayout>
```

the code in MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mymall;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.main_search_icon) {
            //todo:search
            return true;
        }else if (id== R.id.main_notification_icon){
            //todo:notification
            return true;
        }else if (id == R.id.main_cart_icon){
            //todo:cart
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_my_orders) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_rewards) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_carts) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_whislist) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_my_account) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

and the server give me this error:

```
D:\Project Android\My Mall\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:3:6: Error: The value of attribute "xmlns:tools" associated with an element type "FrameLayout" must not contain the '<' character.
```

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: You can't have a FrameLayout as the root of the strings.xml file

Comment: looks like you are missing Android basics. Please pass some basic tutorials before you continue

Answer (score 1):

Your `strings.xml` file should have `<resources>` tag as root, e.g.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>
</resources>
```

So you have to change your file to:

```
<resources>   
    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="nav_header_title">Android Studio</string>
    <string name="nav_header_subtitle">android.studio@android.com</string>
    <string name="nav_header_desc">Navigation header</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title_activity_main">MainActivity</string>
</resources>
```